# Adding Pushpins on bing map in windows form application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, bing-maps

I am a newbie 
I have a database with addresses and longitude/ lattitude data. 
I want to write a small windows application that is able to put multiple pushpins or other marks on the map using longitude and lattitude-

1. The user types ind the address
2. The system gets the longitude and laittude and adds the pushpins on the map. 
   I really need some help and  guidance to get started. 
   I can manage th database call and gui stuff, but i havent been able to successfully adding a bing map and set the pushpins in a simple winform application yet. 
   Im using visual studio 2012 
   I have downloaded and installed the Bing Maps WPF control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So adding a map to a wpf app is super easy. Following the steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745791.aspx

I'll quickly go over the steps mentioned in the article:

Step 1. You have already completed since you have the Bing Maps WPF control.
Step 2. Get a Bing Maps Key
Step 3. Add the xmlns:m annotation to your Window 
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF" 
Step 4. Add a maps Control to your Window. It will be nested within something like the 
Like this

```
<Grid>
    <m:Map x:Name="myMap"
        CredentialsProvider="Your Key From Step 2"/>
</Grid>
```

Step 5. In your Code behind, add pins to your map

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = new Location(37.1481402218342, -119.644248783588);

        // Adds the pushpin to the map.
        myMap.Children.Add(pin);

        // Removes pushpin from the map.
        // myMap.Children.Remove(pin);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, Now im challenged on zooming in on the location of the pushpin. Or in other words zooming in on any location given. Im trying the MyMap.zoomLevel = 16; but it zooms in some where in the pasicic. How do i use the center member.

Comment: Forget my comment, got it to work. Just need to be patient and think about what im doing. i did following :  Map.Center = new Location(37.1481402218342, -119.644248783588);

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get the pushpins to work as well as the zoom level. If my answer helped you out, please mark it as accepted. Good luck on your project.